# How to draw circlemarkers for multiple values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I currently have a circlemarker which create circles of red colour for the unhealthy instances.

Now on this same world map, I wish to have circles of green color as well for the **healthy** instances.

To give an example, City name "Phoenix" can have 20 unhealthyinstances and 3 healthyinstances. So in this case I would like to have a circle of RED color for unhealthy instances and a circle of green color for healthy instances for Phoenix.

```
{
    CityMapData.map((city, index) => {
    const {
            unhealthyInstancesCount,
            healthyInstancesCount,
            entityName,
            totalInstancesCount,
            timeZoneData,
          } = city;

    return (
            <CircleMarker
            key={index}
            center={timeZoneData.coordinates}
            radius={10 * Math.log(unhealthyInstancesCount+ 1)}
            fillOpacity={0.5}
            stroke={false}
            color={COLORS.RED}
            >
           );
    })
}
```

Comment: Pass in a different `color` property? And swap out `unhealthyInstancesCount` for `healthyInstancesCount`?

Comment: Let's say healthy is boolean.  color={healthy ? COLORS.GREEN : COLORS.RED}

Comment: @DBS So if I swap out the value then I to make 2 declarations of circlemarkers to cover both healthy and unhelath. but it doesnt let me declare 2 circlemarkers.

Comment: @BK52 the same city can have both unhealthy and healthy instances. And size of the radius of the circle is depended on unhealthyinstances count and healthyinstancescount. So the boolean part wont solve the radius issue

Comment: So what is **healthy** condition? How can you calculate it?

Comment: You ask this question for marker color. So you can change *color={healthyInstancesCount> unhealthyInstancesCount  ? COLORS.GREEN : COLORS.RED }* . If radius also depended **healthy** apply same condition this field.  *radius={ healthy ? HealthyRadius() : UnhealthyRadius() }*

Comment: The loops runs once for each city, meaning if a city has both unhealthy and healthy instances than how will the boolean value decide ? @BK52

Comment: So what is healthy condition? Is that healthyInstancesCount > unhealthyInstancesCount

Comment: @BK52 Basically it is just data. To give you an example, City name "Phoenix" can have 20 unhealthyinstances and 3 healthyinstances. So in this case I would like to have a circle of RED color for unhealthy instances and a circle of green color for healthy instances for Phoenix

Answer (score -1):

Just choose color depending on a condition and pass unhealthyInstancesCount and healthyInstancesCount as instancesCount to this component wherever you need

```
const {
          instancesCount
          entityName,
          totalInstancesCount,
          timeZoneData,
          isHealthy
    } = city;

return (
    <CircleMarker
    key={index}
    center={timeZoneData.coordinates}
    radius={10 * Math.log(instancesCount+ 1)}
    fillOpacity={0.5}
    stroke={false}
    color={isHealthy ? COLORS.GREEN : COLORS.RED}
>
```

Comment: it is not possible to change the structure city, as it is being used elsewhere as well. @Oleg Brazhnichenko